# jquery get href value new selected class

Tags: jquery, html, css

hi i have an html snippet as below:-

```
<ul id="userTabs" class="clearfix">

                <li class="selected"><a href="">Profile Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="/test">test</a></li>

                <li><a href="/test2">test2</a></li>

                <li><a href="/test3">test3</a></li>

                <li><a href="/test4">test4</a></li>


    </ul>
```

my jquery code snippet is-

```
$("#userTabs li").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#userTabs li").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  var href = $('li:selected a').attr('href');
  alert(href);

});
```

now the issue is, i need to get a value o href when i click a link, the above code will replace current selected class to new selected link.But i cant get the selected class href value. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code please:

```
$("#userTabs li").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#userTabs li").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  var href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
  alert(href);

});
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you've used a `:` instead of a `.` on this line:

```
var href = $('li:selected a').attr('href');
//              ^-- This should be a . since `selected` is a class name
```

But you could just use the reference to the `li` to get its child `a` element instead of traversing the entire DOM again:

```
var href = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
```

And even better, you could delegate the event handler to the `ul` element which would be much more efficient (only one event handler instead of one for each `li` element):

```
var tabs = $("#userTabs");
tabs.on("click", "li", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    tabs.children(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    var href = $(this).addClass("selected").children("a").attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
var href = $("li.selected a").attr("href");
```

or

```
$("#userTabs li a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
   $("#userTabs li").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
   var href = $("li.selected a").attr("href");
   alert(href);
})
```

Comment: This does not work and with the missing ```e.preventDefault();``` causes a page reload

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong when trying to pull the href, tested and works as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5EGH/)

```
$("#userTabs li").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#userTabs li").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  alert(href);

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may be helpful to you.
use this jquery, use missed the child `a`

```
$("#userTabs li a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#userTabs li").removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
var href = $(this).attr('href');
alert(href);
});
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFk6j/)